# How to get absolute positioned div to go off the screen on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have a container that is positioned absolute and is set to be off the screen to the right. When I click a certain button, it slides in from the right to show the content. When you click a close button, it slides back off the screen to the right where it is hidden again. It works well on desktop, however on mobile instead of being hidden off the side of the screen, it shrinks the main content down to half the width and shows the absolutely positioned element next to it. When I click the button that makes it slide in, the container grows to the full with and so does the main content behind it. When I click the close button, instead of the container sliding off the screen, it slides to the right and both containers take up half of the width of the screen.

Here is the html structure and associated css

```css
html {
  width: 100vw;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  background-image: url(./images/sand.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.holder {
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

.work-holder {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 96%;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: scroll;
  transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  right: -100%;
  color: #616161;
  font-family: 'Arsenal', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  padding-bottom: 65px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="holder"></div>
  <div class="work-holder"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the link to the site, I'm not sure if I'm allowed to put this but if you look at it on mobile you can see what I'm talking about. It is the 'work' container. 
https://linx97.github.io/portfolio/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

right : -100%

put

left: -100% ;

this will push to the whole block to the left 100% of the width of the phonescreen

Comment: If you look at the site, I have one block that slides in from the left and one that slides in from the right. The one that slides in from the left is set to left: -100% and that one is working correctly. I would like the other one to slide in from the right, if possible,  which is why it's at right: 100%